# Unit Test of FormControl in Angular 9: TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of null (Validators.compose)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angular9

I always get the error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of null
with **Validators.compose**
when trying to test the below code

```
this.form.controls.phoneNumber.setValidators([
Validators.compose([this.utilsService.conditionalRequired(isRequired)]), Validators.pattern(Regex[regexKey])
]);
```

any idea how can I mock (**Validators.compose**) part?

Answer (score 1):

These 'validate' of undefined (or null in your case) are tough to find out the cause, but generally make sure that everything is defined before it's being used.

Below is how you instantiate your FormGroup, that a component then does a .addControl or a setValidators

```
let formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();
let mockFormGroup: FormGroup = formBuilder.group({phoneNumber:new FormControl(this.obj.id, Validators.required));});
```

You'll also need to make a MockUtilsService and provide it into the spec